# WorldEditChanging everyother block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

In WorldEdit, if i have a line of blocks for a minecart track and I wanted to change every 7th block to a redstone block, what would be the command?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind all the other blocks underneath the tracks being just one type, you can use [the command `//stack`](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Region_operations#Stacking). Here is how to use it:

1. Place a redstone block underneath the tracks.
2. Select the redstone block and six other blocks underneath the tracks with the wand.
3. Look in the direction the tracks are going.
4. Say `//stack [distance_of_tracks / 7]`, e.g. `//stack 10` if the tracks are 70 blocks long.

Comment: The problem with that is the redstone won't power the track through the stone. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this site: [WorldEdit Commands](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference)
You will probably need to write a script.

Comment: That's what it's looking like